# Prove that if $c$ is any element in a field $\mathbb{F}$ and $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}$, then $f(x) \equiv f(c)$ mod $(x-c)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I believe I'm supposed to produce something of the from $f(x)-f(c) = (x-c)p(x)$ where $p(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]$, however I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: You meant $f(x)\in F[x]$. Then $f(x+c)-f(c)$ has $0$ in its roots it implies that it is $=x g(x)$. No need that $F$ is a field.

Comment: $f(x) \equiv f(c) \mod (x-c)$ just means that $x-c$ divides $f(x) - f(c)$. Since c is a root of $f(x)-f(c)$, by the factor theorem $(x-c)$ divides $f(x)-f(c)$. So I think that's all you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by using the division algorithm to show that there exists polynomials $g(x), h(x)\in \mathbb{F}[x]$ such that $f(x) = (x-c)g(x) + h(x)$ and $\deg{h(x)} < \deg{(x-c)} = 1$.

Thus, $h(x)$ must be a constant, lets call it $a$.

Then, plug in the value $c$ for $x$ to get, $f(c) = (c-c)g(x) + a = 0\cdot g(x) + a = a$

$\Rightarrow f(c) = a$

$\Rightarrow f(x) = (x-c)g(x) + h(x) = (x-c)g(x) + a = (x-c)g(x) + f(c)$

Thus, you have proved your result.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to FAQs.

Comment: Again, this isn't a dupe answer. This is one way of proving the required result.

Comment: Again, it is a dupe of the linked answer(s).